# Linux thin client OS supporting RDP 7.1 and PXE?

Tags: linux, rdp, thin-client

We are trying to come up with a workable solution for a number of branch offices. Thin clients (based on existing PC hardware) need to connect back to a Windows 2008 R2 RDS server farm with load balancing. The clients need to support RDP 7.1 so that the users don't get prompted mutliple times for their credentials.

We have tried ThinStation - boots from CD, but can't get SSO working - can't get it to boot from PXE at all, the boot process crashes out with no error and machine restarts

Have also looked at cult (doesn't seem to have seen any dev love for some time) and OpenthinOS. OpenthinOS looks really promising but can't seem to find any support for FreeRDP and to my understanding, that's the only Linux RDP client that currently supports RDP 7.1/brokers/SSO.

Interested to hear if anyone has any experience of this type of setup, at the moment we're banging our heads against a brick wall!!

Thanks

Comment: xfreerdp works very well as a RDP client on linux. Supports NTLM etc.

Comment: @slm thanks for that info, I thought that was probably the case. Do you know a thin client distro that includes it? Pref. one that will run from PXE?

Comment: Ubuntu includes freerdp in the repo.  You can set it up to do LTSP.